# Mostrar el cogido ascii de cada letra de una palabra ingresada por teclado con while o Do while, en VisualBasic

Tags: vb, ascii

TENGO ESTO PERO CON FOR, NECESITO CON UN `WHILE` O `DO WHILE`, POR FAVOR

```
Imports System.Console

Module ASCII

Sub Main()
    Dim orig As String, dest As String
    Dim caracter As String
    Dim asci As Integer

    dest = ""
    WriteLine("Ingresa algo pete")
    orig = ReadLine() 'Origen de texto a convertir

    For i = 1 To Len(orig)
        caracter = Mid(orig, i, 1)
        asci = Asc(caracter)
        dest = dest + "-" + CStr(asci)
    Next i

    WriteLine(dest) 'Destino de la conversión
    ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Como sugerencia, aquí es necesario evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo la utilidad de lo que pides, el resultado es idéntico. Declaras la variable i como integer y la incrementas en cada ciclo.

```
Imports System.Console

Module ASCII

Sub Main()
    Dim orig As String, dest As String
    Dim caracter As String
    Dim asci As Integer

    dest = ""
    WriteLine("Ingresa algo pete")
    orig = ReadLine() 'Origen de texto a convertir
    Dim i as integer

    Do While i <= Len(orig)
        caracter = Mid(orig, i, 1)
        asci = Asc(caracter)
        dest = dest + "-" + CStr(asci)
        i = i + 1
    loop

    WriteLine(dest) 'Destino de la conversión
    ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Amigo, me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de `Do - While` es la siguiente:

```
Do
    //El código a ejecutarse
Loop While condición
```

Para tu código quedaría:

```
Do
    caracter = Mid(orig, i, 1)
    asci = Asc(caracter)
    dest = dest + "-" + CStr(asci)

    i += 1 //Sumas la variable para el ciclo

Loop While i <= Len(orig) //La condición que debe cumplir `i` para que continúe el ciclo
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ahora avance hasta aqui, pero la lectura de la cadena tiene que ser con el while tipo asi pero me da un error en la condicion con cadena:

    
        Dim cadena As String
        Dim caracter As Char

        WriteLine("Ingrese la palabra: ")

        While caracter >= cadena
            cadena = Read()
            caracter = Chr(cadena)
            WriteLine("Caracter pulsado: {0}", caracter)
            WriteLine("Codigo ASCII: {0}", cadena)
        End While
        WriteLine("Ejemplo Terminado")
        ReadKey()

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar ahí el código para que se comprenda mejor.